# How to assign apps startup to a speacial key?

Tags: 22.04

So, I have redmi notebook pro, and it comes with a special key on the top right corner. I want to use this key to open visual studio code. Is there any possible way to do that?

Comment: It comes with a special key that might be so special that users not owning the redmi notebook pro may not have a clue what you are talking about. If it is a very special key, you probably will not be able to open visual studio code with it. Give more information. Indicate what you tried already,

Comment: @vanadium It's a special key, that's placed on the top right, when you click it on ubuntu, it does not work, but when I try using it on the windows, it opens the app I assign it. To assign the apps on the window, I think I had a mi app. What information do you need?

Comment: It will be good to edit your question and add this specific information about your laptop. It is a matter of making the question itself clear. You may understand that not a lot of people will have many clues if you refer to a "special key on the top right corner". Run `xev` and see whether hitting that key shows a key code.